# jquery: link open

Tags: jquery

I found following code
Works excellent

I want to know how to do this

open link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=jquery
when clicked on 
http://stackoverflow.com

is this possible ?
new to jquery

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <!--

   Created using /
   Source can be edited via /uwogi4/2/edit

 -->
 <head>
 <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <meta charset=utf-8 />
 <title>Test Page</title>
 <!--[if IE]>
   <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-               ->
 <style>
   article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
   menu, nav, section { display: block; }
   body {
     font-family: sans-serif;
   }
   p {
     margin: 0px;
   }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div>Foo <span class='pc_more'>http://www.google.com</span></div>
   <div>Bar <span class='pc_more'>http://webvikas.net.in</span></div>
 <script>
 jQuery(function($) {

   $('div').click(function() {
     window.location = $(this).find('.pc_more').html();
   });

 });
 </script>
 <script src="/js/render/edit.js"></script>
 <script>var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-1656750-13'],['_trackPageview']];(function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.src='//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)})(document,'script')</script></body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the good old `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple:

```
$('.pc_more').click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).html();
});
```

Why would you want to do this? Making links and redirects like this is just plain wrong. a-tags were invented for a reason...THIS ONE.

You could simply do:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=jquery" target="_blank">http://stackoverflow.com</a>
```